# placing df.describe().loc['top'] and df.describe().loc['freq'] into a graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been able to extract the top answers from my survey and the frequency of them being used by doing:

```
 df.describe().loc['top'] 
df.describe().loc['freq']
```

how can I go about placing them into a pie chart?
I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Top answers': [df.describe().loc['top']],
                   'Frequency': [df.describe().loc['freq']]},
                  index=['Most Common answer', 'Frequency'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y=df.describe().loc['freq'], figsize=(5, 5))
```

but get the error:

None of [Int64Index([2, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]

how can I get around this? Tried researching how to do this and haven't found anything, is what I'm trying to do possible or do I need to do something with the values first?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. It's with y in `plot()`, which should be a column name or an int: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html#pandas-dataframe-plot-pie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.plot.pie`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html).

If in `df` the answer is in column `ans`, you can use

```
(df.ans.value_counts() / len(df)).plot.pie()
```

to get the frequencies as a pie chart.

As an aside, note that pie charts are [not considered good for visualization](https://blog.funnel.io/why-we-dont-use-pie-charts-and-some-tips-on-better-data-visualizations), as people can't  discern angle ratios very well.

Comment: thank you! An thanks for the side note as well, I'll look to display it differently